Adding Kaitais "doc" to output
How do we access more of the data in Kaitai Struct KSY files in the parsed output of a target file?
I'm specifically looking to get access to the "doc" values for each attribute that has one set as this will be used for easier knowing in depth what I'm looking at when parsing a file.
I could not find anything about it in the documentation that stood out as obvious. And here the Kaitai IDE does not print it either:

The ksy definition top left contains the "doc", but not the object at bottom nor the json to the right has it. I simply need more output than what I currently have. Adding --debug when converting the yaml/ksy file adds a lot of what I wanted as well, but not the doc string.
Any help would be appreciated.
